# Tools to produce cool network drawings

Tags: networking, graph, visualization

I'm looking for some tools to draw a directed graph with relatively small number of nodes (up to 50). As it is meant to be shown to non-technical people - I need my graph to be descriptive and PRETTY. Additionally I need to use some custom images (word-clouds) as nodes - can anyone give an example of a tool that would work for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), where using custom images for nodes is certainly [possible](http://www.graphviz.org/content/kennedyanc). Prettyness is also feasible, at least in my opinion.